# Using the PHP explode function with session variables

Tags: php, session-variables, explode

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong when I combine the explode function with session variables. I've done a decent amount of research already on session variables AND the explode function, but I've had trouble finding help on "combining" the two.

Below is the code I'm using. You'll notice that `$_SESSION['shirt_type']` is being "exploded". This variable collects two pieces of info, the shirt type and price. I want to explode `$_SESSION['shirt_type']` into two chunks.

However, when I try to echo chunk[0] or [1] using the following,

```
echo "Shirt Type = {$_SESSION['$shirt_type_chunks[0]']}<br>";
echo "Shirt Price = {$_SESSION['$shirt_type_chunks[1]']}<br>";
```

My web page echos the following

```
Shirt Type = 
Shirt Price =
```

I believe I have the syntax wrong and I have not been able to find any place that demonstrates the correct syntax when trying to echo an exploded session variable.

Any help that can be offered will be GREATLY appreciated. Also, I've VERY new to StackOverflow so if I've posted something incorrectly, I apologize.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['shirt_type'] = $_POST['shirt_type'];
$_SESSION['shirt_type_chunks'] = explode("|", $shirt_type);

$_SESSION['shirt_size'] = $_POST['shirt_size'];
$_SESSION['shirt_size_chunks'] = explode("|", $shirt_size);

$_SESSION['shirt_qty'] = $_POST['shirt_qty'];

$_SESSION['price'] = $_SESSION['$shirt_type_chunks[1]'] + $_SESSION['$shirt_size_chunks[1]'];
?>
</head>
<body>
<p>
  <?php
    session_start();

    echo "Shirt Type = {$_SESSION['$shirt_type_chunks[0]']}<br>";
    echo "Shirt Price = {$_SESSION['$shirt_type_chunks[1]']}<br>";
    echo "Shirt Up Charge = {$_SESSION['$shirt_size_chunks[1]']}<br>";
    echo "Shirt Size = {$_SESSION['$shirt_type_chunks[0]']}<br>";
    echo "Shirt Qty = {$_SESSION['shirt_qty']}<br>";

    echo "Price = {$_SESSION['price']}<br>";
  ?>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should start session *before any* output.
Change your code to:

```
<? session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
...
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<?
$_SESSION['shirt_type'] = $_POST['shirt_type'];
$_SESSION['shirt_type_chunks'] = explode("|", $shirt_type);
$_SESSION['shirt_size'] = $_POST['shirt_size'];
$_SESSION['shirt_size_chunks'] = explode("|", $shirt_size);

$_SESSION['shirt_qty'] = $_POST['shirt_qty'];

$_SESSION['price'] = $_SESSION['$shirt_type_chunks[1]'] + $_SESSION['$shirt_size_chunks[1]'];
?>
</head>
```

Second thing you have wrong here is that $_SESSION['shirt_type'] and $shirt_type can be the same variable if `register_global = on` on your system. Try to avoid using same names for variables as for global variables, such as $_POST['some_name'] and $some_name or $_SESSION['var_name'] and $var_name

And the third issue, noticed by @brenjt, you need only one call for `session_start()` in your script.

Fourth =) `$_SESSION['$shirt_type_chunks[1]']` won't  work. Using single quotes in PHP means that interpreter will not even try to find any variable in your string. Small example:

```
<?
$a = "Mike";
echo "Hi, my name is $a"; // will output Hi, my name is Mike
echo 'Hi, my name is $a'; // will output Hi, my name is $a
echo 'Hi, my name is '.$a; // will output Hi, my name is Mike
?>
```

Third way is a most efficient because in this case PHP sees single quotes and do not spend resources to analyse string. So change it to  `$_SESSION[$shirt_type_chunks[1]]`

Here is what, as I suppose, you was heading to:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<?php
$shirtDetails = explode("|", $_POST['shirt_type']);
$_SESSION['shirt_type'] = $shirtDetails['0'];
$_SESSION['shirt_price'] = $shirtDetails['1'];

$sizeDetails = explode("|", $_POST['shirt_size']);
$_SESSION['shirt_size'] = $sizeDetails[0];
$_SESSION['shirt_up_charge'] = $sizeDetails[1];
$_SESSION['shirt_qty'] = $_POST['shirt_qty'];

$_SESSION['price'] = $_SESSION['shirt_qty'] * $_SESSION['shirt_price'] + $_SESSION['shirt_up_charge'];
?>
</head>
<body>
<p>
  <?php
    echo 'Shirt Type = '.$_SESSION['shirt_type'].'<br>';
    echo 'Shirt Price = '.$_SESSION['shirt_price'].'<br>';
    echo 'Shirt Up Charge = '.$_SESSION['shirt_up_charge'].'<br>';
    echo 'Shirt Size = '.$_SESSION['shirt_size'].'<br>';
    echo 'Shirt Qty = '.$_SESSION['shirt_qty'].'<br>';
    echo 'Total Price = '.$_SESSION['price'].'<br>';
  ?>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

One final question - why you not just create single input for each form property? Why you want this data to be concatenated by |, is it really necessary?

Comment: You'll also want to mention that he should remove the second `session_start()` call.

Comment: @brenjt, i haven't noticed the second one, tnx

Comment: Hello Everyone, I've asked 3 questions, earned 16 rep & 3 badges but somehow I was banned from posting questions. I understand there is a higher standard of questions here than a traditional forum, but I didn't know until my 2nd post. I never posted insults, asked bogus questions and as soon as I learned of the higher standards here, I (thought) made the necessary changes in all subsequent questions. I'm a HS tech teacher, software guy not coding but my students have really been asking about coding and that is why I'm here. Any suggestions 4 getting unbanned? I read http://goo.gl/C1Kwu THANKS!